# Collective communication - some-to-all broadcasting?

Tags: algorithm, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, inter-process-communicat

I know there's broadcast mechanism where one proc sends msg to all others, and there's all-to-all broadcast where all procs send msgs to all others.

Does anyone know of any mechanism to do similar to all-to-all but only certain number of processors can do the broadcasting? Suppose I have n processors, but I only want x processors among those do the broadcasting.

Edit: I'm using MPI. There's MPI_Bcast and MPI_alltoall, but there isn't anything that let me specify a group of x number of procs that can do the broadcasting.

Comment: Sure: send a one-to-one message to each processor that should receive the message. Exactly how you do this, or any ways of facilitating it by e.g. defining processor groups, depends on the library you're using. Please edit your question to include this information; otherwise, your question is too broad to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MPI has the concepts of "group" and "communicator", which you may use to define groups of processes (notice that many MPI functions take an `MPI_Comm` as a parameter). I don't know how to work with those, but [this article seems to be a decent introduction](http://static.msi.umn.edu/tutorial/scicomp/general/MPI/communicator.html).